# Open iOS Settings App in Specific Section

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am aware of this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

which opens Settings App and takes you directly to the settings related to YOUR app. But I would like to go to a specific section in the Settings app. For my case, I specifically would like to open Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take three separate steps to allow your app to open specific sections in Settings.

First, open up the `Info` section of a project's target. Then expand the URLTypes section at the bottom.  Add  `prefs` to the URL Schemes textbox

[image]

Next, put this code in your app where you want the specific section of Settings to open.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=General&path=About"]]
```

Finally, change the text in the URL string to indicate the section you want -- here's the list of possibilities:

```
prefs:root=General&path=About
prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
prefs:root=Brightness
prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
prefs:root=FACETIME
prefs:root=General
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
prefs:root=MUSIC
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
prefs:root=General&path=Network
prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
prefs:root=NOTES
prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
prefs:root=Phone
prefs:root=Photos
prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
prefs:root=General&path=Reset
prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
prefs:root=Safari
prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
prefs:root=Sounds
prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
prefs:root=STORE
prefs:root=TWITTER
prefs:root=FACEBOOK
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE prefs:root=VIDEO
prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
prefs:root=Wallpaper
prefs:root=WIFI
prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING`
```

It looks like `prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES` is the one you'd want. Plus, this will only work for iOS 8 and higher.

Edited to Add:  **This information is not official and is not supported by Apple in their documentation. This code may break in future iOS releases and may cause issues with App Store review.**

Comment: Can you share where this is officially documented?

Comment: Actually, I pulled this from various places here on SO.  But you might take look at these two entries in these Apple developer forums (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21886 & https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/65964#65964) -- though it works well in testing, it's not clear if the use of the `prefs` scheme will pass Review.

Comment: You should make it clear that this is not official, not supported, may break in future iOS releases (as it already did in the past), and may cause issues with App Store review.

Comment: Thanks, @jcaron you're right -- I've added that note to my answer.

Comment: I just submitted an Enhancement Request to Apple asking that the unofficial "prefs" scheme be made official. I'll post their response here.

Answer (score 0):

GlennRay's answer is correct in implementation but just to add a little more info.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1924/_index.html

Apple specifically state that only the keyboard settings is supported and all other values to open to a specific section are a violation of the App Review guidelines.